# Android Cordova App crash signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr

Tags: android, cordova, crash-dumps

Scenario: The app constantly tracks the Geolocation of the device and when there is no user interaction for a while (varies between 5- 10 mins) The app crashes.

When user is interacting with app there is no crashing. The logcat trace as below.

```
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Build: samsung/chagallltedo/chagalllte:5.0.2/LRX22G/T805YDOU1BOG1:user/release-keys
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Hardware: universal5420 D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Revision: 7 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Bootloader: T805YDOU1BOG1 D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Radio: unknown 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.39-5331373 (dpi@SWDD6318) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 6 17:07:24 KST 2015 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/chagallltedo/chagalllte:5.0.2/LRX22G/T805YDOU1BOG1:user/release-keys' 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): Revision: '7' D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): ABI: 'arm' 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): pid: 20024, tid: 20073, name: RenderThread  >>> com.example.test <<< 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): processName:com.example.test 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2960): broadcastEvent : com.example.test SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE 
W/ContextImpl( 2960): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1714 
com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:296 
com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 
com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 
com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102 
D/PhoneWindow( 2960): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null 
D/PhoneWindow( 2960): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false 
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2313): id=1402 createSurf (97x97),1 flag=4, nidig I/OpenGLRenderer( 2960): Initialized EGL, version 1.4 I/OpenGLRenderer( 2960): HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x9e13c268 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = -1709931596 E/android.os.Debug( 2960): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error 
I/dumpstate(21554): begin I/dumpstate(21554): dumpstate is still running 
D/SensorService( 2960): [SO] 0.450 0.153 9.874 W/ActivityManager( 2960): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{247b8582 u0 
com.example.test/.TelerikCallbackActivity t418 f} 
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService( 2960): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1800000  uid : 1000  pid : 2960  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@2 
W/ActivityManager( 2960): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
```

Has anyone come across similar problems? My guess is I need to take network communication off the UI thread but I am not sure if that will fix it.